# How do I package up a windows driver for deployment?

Tags: windows, deployment, installation, package, device-driver

I have a windows driver which is sys and inf files which I need to package up for deployment on end user systems.

How do I do this and what tools can I use?

Comment: Which kind of windows driver you have?

Comment: It is a driver for a USB device

Answer (score 1):

I use [AdvancedInstaller](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) for building my MSI files, which also has the ability to install drivers using [DIFx 2.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544838(v=VS.85).aspx). Never used it to install drivers myself, but it can do it.

They have a trial version so you could give it a spin at no loss.